# How can I access GNOME Tweaks settings directly?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, theme

GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`, ex. `gnome-tweak-tool`) is reporting an error that the extension to choose your GNOME shell theme is not enabled, although it is.

Is there any way to manually override it, other than through the tool itself?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here using dconf, and it works great, tested it myself

http://asingh.com.np/blog/how-to-enable-desired-gnome-shell-theme/

using dconf navigate to:

> org > gnome > shell > extensions > user-theme

and change

> name

field to the directory of the theme :-).  It doesn't have to be an absolute path, just the name of the directory in the ~./themes folder